Problema en método recursivo que modifica el valor de un parámetro a 0
Buen día.
Estoy trabajando en un método recursivo que se encarga de registrar unas instancias de la Entidad Actividad en base de datos.
Como podrán ver en el código cada instancia de Actividad tiene otras actividades hijas a las cuales después de haber registrado las actividades padre se les pase el id de estos, mas el id de una instancia Objetivo, inicialmente funciona bien, la primera actividad se registra bien, pero cuando sigue con las actividades hijas, no entiendo porque pero el id del objetivo se vuelve 0, lo que genera un error de referencias.
Este es el código.
async Task<bool> AgregarActividades(ICollection<PNActividad>? actividades, int? actividadID, int objetivoID)
        {
            if (actividades == null || actividades.Count == 0) return false;

            foreach (var actividadaux in actividades)
            {
                actividadaux.AuditCreateDate = DateTime.Now;
                actividadaux.AuditCreateUser = 1; //TODO modificar por el id del usuario loguedo
                actividadaux.ActividadPadreID = actividadID;
                actividadaux.ObjetivoEspecificoID = objetivoID;
                _context.PNActividades.Add(actividadaux);
            }

            // Guardar cambios para asegurar que todos los IDs están generados.
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            // Ahora que todos los IDs de las actividades padre están establecidos, podemos agregar las actividades hijas.
            foreach (var actividadaux in actividades)
            {
                await AgregarActividades(actividadaux.Actividades, actividadaux.Id, objetivoID);
            }
            return true;
        }

lo que me viene en mente es que al llamar await _context.SaveChangesAsync(); modifica de alguna manera este ID, pero no sé.

Y seguiste el codigo a ver quien transforma eso a cero???

gbianchi, en ninguna parte del código modifico la variable, a demás como puedes ver es una función recursiva lo que significa que no se saldrá de ella hasta que se cumpla la condición de retorno. de he hecho realice una traza y el primer listado de actividades si se registra bien, el error empieza con las actividades hijas ya que a estas se les pasa 0 como objetivoID y rompe la llave foranea.

Alguien lo transforma a cero... quien sea... no es magia.. o es siempre 0 o alguien lo cambia.. vuelvo a preguntar.. hiciste un seguimiento para ver cuando cambiar a 0?

Hola Esteban, seguramente voy a decir una estupidez, pero... no debería ser await AgregarActividades( actividadaux.Actividades, actividadaux.Id, actividadaux.objetivoID );?.

Lo que te dice gbianchi es que coloques un punto de interrupcción, por ejemplo en el segundo foreach y vayas viendo que valores toma objetivoID, luego del SaveChangesAsync

@Yussef, maestro, idolo... actividadaux.objetivoID vs objetivoID.

@MarcePuente Si ya vi la diferencia, objetivoID entra como argumento de la función, no es parte del objeto actividadaux. Aun cuando podría usar actividadaux.ObjetivoEspecificoID  ya que esa propiedad se setea con ese mismo valor

@Yussef, como siempre, sus comentarios son más acertados que los mios!!!

Prueba a crear una variable temporal y asignarle el valor de objetoId antes de entrar en la primera condición, entonces después que guardes vuelve a darle a objetivoId el valor temporal previamente guardado. También podrías hacer la prueba de no trabajar con el método asíncrono, si así funciona entonces ya sabes que hay problema con la asincrónia, quizás sea una condición de carrera y debas usar un lock otro recurso
